# cygwin + console2: running cygwin bash with startup dir

Tags: windows, bash, command-line, console, cygwin

I am using Console2 as a bash wrapper on Windows. Most importantly, it enables me to start up a new bash tab in a predefined project directory.

Now I would like to replace the Windows command line by a Cygwin bash. However, the "Startup Dir" setting in Console2 is not respected by Cygwin.

Basically, I see three solution approaches:

- Figure out **how the Console2 setting has to look like** so that the Cygwin bash respects it
- Add a **startup parameter** to the Cygwin bash, setting the startup directory
- Automatically **run a script after bash startup** that changes the directory

Searching around in Cygwin's documentation and the rest of the Internet, I could not find a solution to any of those approaches. I could imagine that the solution is trivial to someone else, though. :)

*environment: Win XP, Console 2.00.146, Cygwin 1.7.7, GNU Bash 3.2.51(24)*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As for the last bullet point, edit your `~/.bashrc` and add a `cd` command at the end.

Instead of that, you can try this for your first bullet point: If your Console2 configuration to start Bash looks something like this:

```
bash --login -i
```

change it to:

```
bash --login -i -c 'cd somdir; exec bash'
```

Comment: For the first solution, I added `cd /cygdrive/c/projects` to ` ~/.bashrc`, which has not been executed. Your second solution works, however, after 5 trys. Apparently, it is a necessity to use POSIX paths.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem, saw your post, and then found this answer:

1. Run the Setup.exe Cygwin installer and add the "chere" package
2. In Console2, add a new tab called "Bash" with a shell path of "C:\cygwin\bin\bash". See screenshot.
3. Finally, add the following to the registry: 
   Code:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open Cygwin Here...]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open Cygwin Here...\command] 
@="\"C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.exe\" -t Bash -r \"/bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe '%L'\""

Found this solution at:
http://www.e-texteditor.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=8884

Answer (score 5):

- In Cygwin installer add "chere" package (contains /bin/xhere script)
- Use the following shell command in Console2 settings:

> C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c '/bin/xhere /bin/bash'
>   
>   The shell will run in the current working dir or in the specified "Startup Dir".

Comment: Great answer.  I can now start Console2 from Windows Explorer and it starts in the right directory.  I still had to change the start drive in Console2 settings for when I start it outside of Windows Explorer.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Worked perfectly on latest Console2 version as of this comment.

Answer (score 3):

I had some problems with some with the approaches above (Console2 window screwed up when using c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe as shell, xhere not reflecting my actual working dir).

So I created this batch file and used it as Console2's shell:

C:\cygwin64\cygbash.bat:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -i  -c "/bin/xhere /bin/bash `cygpath -d '%CD%'`"
```

Comment: This works great, **however** if your path has spaces in it you'll need to add -d after cygpath, so instead use something like

`C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -i  -c "/bin/xhere /bin/bash \`cygpath -d '%CD%'\`"`

Comment: I added your suggestion, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I tried variations of all the above, but none worked.  This is what worked for me using Console2 v2.00.148:

1)..Copy the Cygwin.bat to a new file: Cygbash.bat.

2)..Replace the last line to be this: `bash --login -i -c 'cd /cygdrive/c/; exec bash'`

3)..Go into Console2 settings and change the shell to point to this new Cygbash.bat file.

The above will start Console2 in the root of your C drive.
fyi - I'm the original poster, just forgot to login to my account first.

Comment: I am using Console2 v2.00.148 and tried the accepted answer without success.  This answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last bullet point, you can put for example:

```
cd /cygdrive/d
```

in ~/.bash_profile 
This will be picked up when using Console2 and also when you run Cygwin itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the shell dir to:

   `bash --login -i -c 'cd /cygdrive/c/...; exec /bin/bash'`
2. Add this line to the end of `C:\cygwin\home\USERNAME\.profile`

   `cd -`